# Large spacing under map using jquery plugin US map

Tags: jquery, css, spacing

I'm developing a site using US map and I have a large white space under the map image.
Here is the url: http://kiriuminteractive.com/ncshpo/shpodirectory.shtml

I've added all the margin: 0px and padding: 0px I can think of.  Any ideas what is causing this space?  Thanks in advance for your help.

PS: This is my first post, so definitely let me know if you need anything else to give an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                                           ^
                                           |
                        you asked a browser it to be 500px high
                       so it rendered a 500px high block element
```

Comment: I knew it was simple.  I was confused by the example on the site and thought this <div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div> also controlled the size of the map image.  thanks for your quick and helpful response.